# Flat babel output

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've got a project with nested file structure in the `src` directory. Until now, I was using `babel --out-dir lib src`. Recently I've come to an idea to let users use separate files directly, so basically I want to transform this structure:

```
| src/
|   a.js
|   b.js
|   c/
|     d.js
|     e/
|       f.js
```

Into this:

```
| lib/
|   a.js
|   b.js
|   d.js
|   f.js
```

I've already tried `babel --out-dir lib src/*`, `babel --out-dir lib src/**`, `babel --out-dir lib src/**/*.js`, but none of them is working as intended - some copy files multiple times (once at the top level and once in a subdirectory) or only in the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be done using only the `babel` command, since `babel` doesn't have any kind of `--no-recursive` option.

However, if you're not afraid of a semicolon and liberal use of `find`, you can do it in a one-liner:

```sh
babel -d lib $(find src -type d); find lib/* -maxdepth 0 -type d | xargs rm -r
```

Before:

```
$ tree src
src
├── a.js
├── b.js
└── c
    ├── d.js
    └── e
        └── f.js
```

After:

```
$ tree lib
lib
├── a.js
├── b.js
├── d.js
└── f.js
```

Comment: And what about system independent solution?

Comment: @RadosławMiernik You mean you want a solution for Windows? Or, what other system are you asking about.

Comment: Kind of. I'm using Linux, but I'd rather use a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue with babel-cli where it kept overwriting the content of my source files. Solved with a Node script:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

    // glob passes an array of path/filenames into callback as files
    glob('./src/**/*.js', {}, (er, files) => {
        // for each filename
        files.forEach(file => {
            // transform that filename, your presets/plugins may vary
            babel.transformFile(file, {presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'stage-3'], babelrc: false}, (err, result) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(`${file} transpiled`);
                    // if it worked, write it to the new dir (in my case it's root)
                    fs.writeFileSync(`./${result.options.basename}.js`, result.code);
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

Dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.9.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "jest": "^20.0.4"
}
```